# redmine: download wiki.html instead of the wiki page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

as I don't manage to register in the forum in redmine.org, I am copying [this](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/33415) question here with my actual problem.

I am running Redmine 2.1.4 on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.8 .
It is being served by an Apache 2.2.1 in a Debian Linux using Phusion Passenger 2.2.15

When I click on the Wiki of a project, I get a "download Wiki.html" behavior rather than the wiki page itself.

The downloaded Wiki.html has the content of the main Wiki page in a simple HTML format.

Here are my response headers with Content-Disposition clearly provoking this behaviour.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 01:17:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 2.2.15
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
content-transfer-encoding: binary
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Wiki.html"
Cache-Control: private
Status: 200
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 535
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=500
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

This is from the Redmine log:

```
Started GET "/projects/inventory/wiki.html" for 10.98.107.47 at Tue Dec 04 02:17:33 +0100 2012
Processing by WikiController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"inventory"}
  Current user: admin (id=4)
  Rendered wiki/export.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data Wiki.html (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is an error with Redmine, which for some reason is adding the `Content-Disposition:` header.  I think this is a question for the Redmine folks.  You might want to check with a different browser (Firefox, Chrome), as there may be something Redmine needs to do for some broken version of IE -- that would at least narrow it down.

Comment: I had tested it with Firefox 16, but it happens the same with IE 8 and Chrome 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repair my installation by commenting out this line in `redmine/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

Is this directive an important part of Redmine? or Rails? I actually don't know who put all the configurations in .htaccess nor why.

Redmine seems to be working fine, but does anybody know if removing this directive will cause problems somewhere in Redmine?

Comment: This Apache directive is trouble: it says "for all URLs, take up to the first period, replace everything after with `.html` and append any query string.".  So `/foo/bar.html?status=open` would be rewritten to `/foo/bar.html?status=open` -- no change, but `/foo.bar.html` would be rewritten to `foo.html` (which is wrong), and maybe this case `/foo/bar` would be rewritten as `foo/bar.html` is the one that is making the difference.  There's no indication that this is required by redmine (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_212_in_Ubuntu_1210_and_Apache_Passenger)